# Screen settings for Pi?

Tags: screen

I'm working from home and my job gave me a Raspberry Pi to use. I've never used one before, and I have it running but there is no control panel or anything, I just want to add a blue light filter, that's it.

Comment: What Pi? What OS? there are extensive configuration options. What is "a blue light filter?

Comment: I dont know what Pi it is. Blue light filter is just a screen filter so there isnt so much blue light that's bad for your eyes. Is there a control panel or something? I don't know how any of this works

Comment: Depends on the OS you are running

Comment: Please open a terminal session, type `cat /etc/os-release`, and tell us the output.  Please edit that into your question rather than replying as a comment.

Comment: As per this blog, simply using the "warm" setting on your monitor should do: https://nrecursions.blogspot.com/2018/03/alternative-to-flux-for-ubuntu-is.html

Answer (score 4):

Your monitor might have a setting to do with that. My Benq monitor has a built-in "night" setting that provides you with a slightly orange light.

Answer (score 3):

Most Linuxes include a program [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/). Just type

```
man redshift
```

to see if you have it and how to use it.

Comment: Before you recommend redshift, can you confirm (with reproduction steps) that you actually have it working on a Pi?